# Grails Spring Security - security = "none"

Tags: spring, grails, spring-security

For my Grails Spring Security Plugin (2.0-RC2) configuration in `Config.groovy`, is there an equivalent to

```
<http pattern="/css/**" security="none"/>
```

in the XML configuration? I'm attempting to redirect to a failed authentication page (inside a custom filter), but it causes a redirect loop, as the page I am attempting to redirect to is "protected".

I've attempted altering the filter chain map for the specific route that I want to not be secured, but to no avail. It still executes the custom filter where auth fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to alter the filter chain for your URIs. Check out the [filters chapter](http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/guide/filters.html) of the documentation. By altering the filter chain for specific URIs you can control which filters get applied.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing. Thank you. Something to note though: I was originally using `SpringSecurityUtils.clientRegisterFilter()` to add our custom filters to the chain. Doing this will override and changes you have made to the `filterChainMap` in Config.groovy, essentially ignoring your changes. Therefore, you have to manually configure your entire filter chain in order to do what I wanted AND use custom filters.